# How to Debug Libcurl in Xcode 4.5

Tags: c++, xcode, curl, libcurl

we are in the process of porting our application from Windows to OSX and I am having some problems with Curl, unlike the windows version it wont allow me to choose the symbol location in Xcode in order to debug what is going on inside the curl library. I have built Curl from source, and I guess its just a matter of copying the lib and the object files somewhere that it can read it from?

thanks

Comment: Did you compile libcurl with debug symbols? If so Xcode/GDB should automatically pick those up. If you built it without debug symbols, you won't get debug symbols!